# BlackScreen at the WebCam | Ubuntu 16.04 + VMWare

Tags: vmware, webcam

I'm using Windows 8 on my main machine (laptop Asus K56CB) + VMWare with Ubuntu 16.04 installed.
I'm trying to capture a picture from the webcam on Ubuntu , but there is a problem...

My Ubuntu system detects WebCam as USB device:

```
eugen@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsusb
[sudo] password for eugen: 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5165 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

But when I'm running Cheese, there is only Black Screen. 
Only one util is working: guvcview

Util xcam gives me the next error:

```
eugen@ubuntu:/usr/local/share/OpenCV/samples/python$ xcam              
    [xcam]    No vidcams were identified. If you were expecting something
      different, check that the vidcam is plugged in, turned on and
      detected by sane-find-scanner (if appropriate). Please read
      the documentation which came with this software (README, FAQ,
      manpages).
```

eugen@ubuntu:/usr/local/

Whats the problem can be?